# How to get the client's URI/URL in Dart lang?

Tags: dart

I have a small test HTTP server in Dart lang, I want to print the client's URI/URL for every request but I can't find a way to retrieve it, in fact I can't find anything about how to get any info about the client.

Comment: The `HttpRequest` contains the requested URI in `request.uri`. If you want to know where the client got to this from, use the `Referer` header. See: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-io/HttpRequest-class.html The `HttpConnectionInfo` contains lower level information about the connection like port numbers.

Comment: The connectionInfo was what I was looking for, thanks Richard Heap.